# React transition group and Router not showing leave animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have this codepen and while the entering animation fires the exit animation does not. How Would I fix this?

https://codepen.io/jeankvd/pen/aYggwN?editors=0110

```
    <TransitionGroup>
        <Route  exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
    </TransitionGroup>
```

Comment: Please embed your code into the question.

Comment: What kind of effect you'd like to have on exit animation?